# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 along WIndows to dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a computer that already has Windows 7 installed. When going through the installation steps it says that no other OS is found. How do I get back to Windows. I want to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get back to your `windows 7`. You just need to format it then after installing windows 7 you may follow this step in dual booting it. [Dual Booting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNCSbTyUzoM) it's the best tutorial I've seen so far and it worked for me. Even if your in windows 7 It's just the same process though.

Answer (score 0):

I have ecounter this problem too. 
If you understand about hdd partitioning, it is better to choose 'something else' in installation setup 
Create new partition for ubuntu filesystem and swap 
Install ubuntu and you will have dual boot in your computer